# Cheerio get content of p tag within section tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler, cheerio

Cheerio doesn't return the content of a `<p id="target-content">` tag, that is nested between multiple other tags. I use cheerio and request. My code looks like this, but it always returns `null`.

I try to get the content of paragraph with id `id=target-content`.

```
var webpage = '...';
request(webpage, function(err, res, body) {
if (err) console.err(err);
if (res.statusCode === 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    $('p[id="target-content"]').text(); // returns null
}
});


<body>
    <div id="foobar">
        <div>...</div>
        <div>...</div>
        <div>...</div>
        <section id="foo">
            <header></header>
            <section id="bar">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <section id="container">
                    <p id="target-content">
                        Stackoverflow is amazing.
                    </p>
                </section>
            </<section>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

I expect the output `Stackoverflow is amazing`, but I get `null` or simply no output at all. I appreciate any help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you check if `res.statusCode === 200` is true and the code within the `if` is executed? Also, how did you check the return value of `$('p[id="target-content"]').text();` - seems that you're missing a `return` or at least a `console.log()`?

Answer (score 0):

1. First because you have been initiate  `if (err) console.err(err);`, i think you didn't need initiate conditional `if(res.statusCode === 200)` again. But that's optional
2. Check first `console.log(res.statusCode)` to check what contain in `res.statusCode`
3. `console.log( $('p[id="target-content"]').text();)` or store in variable like this

```
 const result = $('p[id="target-content"]').text();
 console.log(result) //if still null, try ``console.log $('p[id="target-content"]').data`` again to check with other options, or ``console.log $('p[id="target-content"]')``
 return result
```

I hope this clue may can help you